# How to send video using NetGear

Tags: python, sockets, video, video-streaming

How can I send video from client to server. I have this codes but I can not send from client to server. I am using NetGear. NetGear implements a high-level wrapper around PyZmQ python library that contains python bindings for ZeroMQ - a high-performance asynchronous distributed messaging library that provides a message queue, but unlike message-oriented middleware, its system can run without a dedicated message broker.

I have server with open port. Client destination is to connect to server and send video. Server need to receive that video.

This is server code`

```
# import required libraries
from vidgear.gears import VideoGear
from vidgear.gears import NetGear

# open any valid video stream(for e.g `test.mp4` file)
stream = VideoGear(source="test.mp4").start()

# Define Netgear Server with default parameters
server = NetGear()

# loop over until KeyBoard Interrupted
while True:

    try:

        # read frames from stream
        frame = stream.read()

        # check for frame if Nonetype
        if frame is None:
            break

        # {do something with the frame here}

        # send frame to server
        server.send(frame)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break

# safely close video stream
stream.stop()

# safely close server
server.close()
```

This is client code `

```
from vidgear.gears import NetGear
import cv2


# define Netgear Client with `receive_mode = True` and default parameter
client = NetGear(receive_mode=True)

# loop over
while True:

    # receive frames from network
    frame = client.recv()

    # check for received frame if Nonetype
    if frame is None:
        break

    # {do something with the frame here}

    # Show output window
    cv2.imshow("Output Frame", frame)

    # check for 'q' key if pressed
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if key == ord("q"):
        break

# close output window
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# safely close client
client.close()
```

Comment: You have to tell us what problem you're having. "but I can not send from client to server" is not specific enough.  What errors are your receiving?